# Leading apostrophe is not displayed while dumping the Excel sheet into a MySQL database in a Rails 3 application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, rubygems, spreadsheet

I am using a script to dump the data in to a MySQL database in a Rails 3 application.

I have a cell data in Excel sheet as:

```
'abc
```

While dumping it in to database it only shows as:

```
abc
```

I am doing this on Fedora 15 and using the 'spreadsheet gem' in a script for dumping data.

Comment: Resolved, I have inserted the ' by the script in the record in which ' is not present,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. I have inserted the `'` by the script in the record in which `'` is not present.